# Intro template not rendering background

Tags: rendering

so the intro I'm trying to render looks like this: https://youtu.be/PHIZfv_XcFI?t=373

My issue is that whenever I render animation, it turns out like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdLkE.jpg
I turned off "transparent" in the "film" area and it made it look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxus4.jpg
What am I doing wrong? Why is it only rendering the text with a transparent background?
I've done multiple templates and they all do this, and there doesn't seem to be a single other person with this problem lol. 
Is it something in my output settings? I've tried multiple different ones including quicktime and h.264
I just got blender today.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Blender is only the first step. After you render the Transparent 3D font Layer with Blender you will need to place the output in the Aftereffects composition.

Comment: I may have been using blender + ae intro templates then. I remember in the past using only blender to render these out. I'll try again then.

Comment: If this answered your question please considder accepting the answer, so the question gets closed :)